# PBI Dax: How do I show two total parameters while showing only 1 parameter breakdown?

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

How do I add the highlighted column in my PBI table since it's a different parameter? I only need the total volume of items sold and not the monthly breakdown. At the same time, the monthly revenue needs to be shown in the same table.

PS - I apologize about using image. I know it's hated here.